# Is there a formal definition of what a distinguisher is?

Tags: distinguisher

I've often been reading about (polynomially bounded) distinguishers in books or papers. Although by name and intuition it is somewhat clear what a distinguisher is and does, but i am asking myself whether there is a concrete formal definition. Despite the concept being used frequently, i wasn't able to find one.

Comment: The Wikipedia article on [cryptographic advantage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advantage_(cryptography)) may be of use.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A distinguisher is an **arbitrary** algorithm. In fact, we do NOT want to formalize anything about the distinguisher (except that its output is a single bit, although we don't even really need to do this). In definitions, we require that *no* distinguisher should succeed with non-negligible probability. So, this should hold for any algorithm.

Of course, we do specify the complexity class of the distinguisher (either probabilistic polynomial-time or non-uniform polynomial-time).

Comment: I think that should be "non-negligible advantage", not probability.

Comment: Well, it just depends on what you mean by "succeed". But, yes, this is the intention.

Comment: How would you define "succeed" to fit in this case? I can't think of a natural definition.

Comment: Formally, I meant what you meant. I wouldn't define it differently...

Answer (score 0):

If you need further reading I strongly recommend you having a look at the paper "On the Role of Definitions in and Beyond Cryptography", by Rogaway. There he explains clearly the concept of distinguisher.